# What would be a suitable amusement park for four-legged sentient beings?

Tags: biology, society, fantasy-races

This is something my sister and I have argued about a lot and we can't figure it out ourselves. So help me out here.

In a world where both four-legged (dragons and griffins) and two-legged (humans and anthropomorphic animals) beings live, do you think it is possible to make an amusement park that would work for all of them?

I mean like the sitting place and safety in coasters, or what type of amusement are possible to all types of species?

I have my doubt becauses of the different sizes of all beings, but please tell me if I am wrong if you can figure this siblings' debate out.

Comment: The tricky bit will be finding stuff that's equally entertaining for all. A rollercoaster might be quite exciting for a species that evolved to trot around at a sedate pace on the ground, but for predatory winged species it might be quite relaxing or even dull.

Comment: @Starfish Prime: Even among humans, not everyone finds amusement parks all that amusing.

Comment: There are a number of amusements that could safely entertain without risk for the visitor (with limits, a T-Rex moving around would be a risk anyway). You just need to cancel from your mind the standard amusement park with lots of machinery. But SE does not allow question that require lists as answers.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but my first instinct would be to Google "dog amusement parks", to see if there already exist any parks designed to cater to both two- and four-legged patrons.

Comment: I have NO IDEA that there exist amusement parks for dogs. I will check that one out

Answer (score 9):

Human amusement parks have already different attractions for different sized humans.

In many cases a minimum height is required to access an attraction, and in some cases even a maximum height, in order to ensure safety of the visitor.

[image]

The same concern will apply in your case: a seat designed to hold a human won't work for a rabbit or a cow sized creature.

It's very likely size separation will be enforced. To make it economically viable they might use compartments, like wagons 1 to 3 for dog sized quadrupeds, wagons 4 to 9 for human sized bipeds, wagons 10 to 15 for cow sized quadrupeds.

Comment: this also comes with another problem; what about the four-legged ones if they are the correct size? you can't stuff a dog into a sitting position meant for a human. if only one to two species can ride the coaster, I don't think the amusement park gets enough money for having the coaster up.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything would have to be an enclosed ride with a back strap that held them in place i'd think unless they want to lay on the ridge of their spine.

Other than that alot of water rides :P

Comment: Welcome to the site, John. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions a user has while developing his/her fictional world. To that end, answers are expected to explain why the proposed solution solves the problem; one-liners are strictly discouraged. This post has already been flagged as low-quality and is likely to be deleted unless an [edit] is made to expound on the idea presented here. Feel free to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: Enclosed? Maybe, maybe not ("please keep your hands, arms, ***and wings*** inside the ride at all times"). Unusual harnesses? Definitely, especially considering, again, those pesky wings. Probably you'd need totally different restraints for humans and dragons/griffins, also, as even if their torsos are similar in *size* to a human, they probably aren't very similar in *shape*.

Answer (score 0):

**The glider coaster**

Make a roller coaster that has a 20 foot long carriage (for Humans) or a 40 foot long carriage (for Dragons) with a 20 or 40 foot foot pole (20 for human 40 for Dragons) coming off the front and back it and an attachment point for a 10 foot elastic that attaches harness to user. These elastics will be designed to ensue that the user is constrained to never hit the coaster under and circumstances. This is done by having the elastics essentially confine the user to a flight envelope in-between the front and back coasters. The roller coaster design will be constrained by a lack of overhead and sideways clearance, but otherwise most mid-G coaster designs will work.

**How it works**

Griffins and Dragons spread their wings like they are about to fly and use the speed of roller coaster to fly at full speed while effectively gliding (unpowered by their own wings). Humans can do the same with artificial wings attached to their arms designed to constrain movements that would accidentally put snapping staring on their bones (high drag maneuver that places stress on collar bone). The coaster would also effectively guide dragons into doing complex and typically difficult maneuvers that only expert fliers could perform, but to perform them they would simply keep their wings flat and let the coaster guide them.

**The circle glide coaster (for beginners)**

A simple glider coaster would be a simple circle that would let a dragon or human do as many orbits as they want without any external forces. The humans would get to experience personal controlled flight, and dragons get to fly without having to manually propel themselves. This could also be used for sports as it would give dragons and humans an even playing field for demonstrating interesting flight maneuvers. a large enough glide coaster could even have multiple coasters going at the same time and introduce new ones in the same way cars enter a round about.

**Advanced coasters**

These might have loops, cobras, and other maneuvers to show case different maneuvers. However, these will have to be tested so that they are safe weather you go full drag, minimum drag, roll, or move around to anywhere in the flight envelope.

**Safety and popularity**

Glide coasters like these would be a huge attraction to dragons and humans alike, but there would be a good reason for that. Even basic versions of this would be very rare since it is definitely more high thrill and high risk. You would need to ensure that no dragon has a lift or drag capability that exceeds the limits of the coaster, and the activity would have more in common with sky diving than a spinning tea cup. That said, a place like Coney island may be able to justify it as a high thrill ride or spectator sport for the non-rider onlookers.

Answer (score 0):

**There are a two main considerations to take into account**

1. volume of visitor
2. wings or lack of wings of visitor

When you think of rides that dragons can't ride you of course think of roller coasters, but stuff that is designed for human butts isn't going to work on dragons

Volume disqualifies small chair rides, like roller coasters, tea cups, any thing tracked that only has smaller size carriages.

Wings can be accounted for if the riders keep their wings in the dart or have them bound so they don't accidentally create drag, but you would want a ride that doesn't have these pitfalls and work with everyone.

I present the [Graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitron). The gravitron is a spinning chamber that produces moderate G forces with centripetal force. The key thing is that volume and wings have little effect and people can be placed anywhere in the ride interchangeably. You will want to build the ride a little stronger than normal since more G acceleration on a larger mass like a Dragon or Griffin will apply more force to the walls.

Answer (score 0):

## Dragon's Breath (Frame Challenge)

I would suggest that the biggest hurdle to your amusement park is not the size or number of legs of your guests.  It is dragon's breath.

Traditionally, dragons breath fire.  Other versions spit acid or shoot lightning.  In some universes they can do more than one or it can vary by dragon.

Why is this an issue?  Because in many modern amusement parks, the rides are thrill rides.  Rides designed to make the guest feel fear and exhilaration.  To make you scream and to make your heart race.

The problem is, when a dragon gives into their primal fear and roars, it tends to come out badly for whatever is in front of their mouth.  Be it another guest, or the car or other element of the ride.

Your dragon thrill rides need to be able to take into account what kind of breath a thrilled dragon might uncontrollably emit.  Protect the other guests.  Have struts that can survive both steel melting flames and stone melting acid.  An enclosed cart might do it, but will reduce the effectiveness of the ride and might also put the individual dragon at risk from splash back.  Even then, the cars would be heavy and expensive, and might not be viable as a ride vehicle.

Unless you are allowing for magic, I think a dragon amusement park ride is going to be a non-starter.

Comment: easy fix: species with dangerous breath would have to ride in a car with a plexiglass windshield... or in this case, sapphire glass windshield. Spitting species might do away with just face masks.